# Android WifiP2pManager Encryption / Secure

Tags: android, encryption, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager

I have built a basic app that can send messages to other phones with the app without required a WiFi AP thanks to the WifiP2pManager class.

However, I am now trying to secure the messages transferred through the app, and I unsure on how to best do this securely.

I would like to use a form of public key encryption, but as the app is designed to function without access to the Internet I am unsure on the best method to approach this, as the key would need to be shared when the devices connect.

Would using SSLSockets be suitable? How would one go about using this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

WiFi P2P (Direct) connections are encrypted by default with WPA2. The authentication phase of the connections uses WPS (Push dialog which has to be accepted by a user) and a key is exchanged to setup WPA2. Once the group is formed you can get the encryption key using [WifiP2pGroup.getPassphrase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pGroup.html#getPassphrase()).

Communication is already pretty secure (assuming the devices successfully connected without anyone screwing with the connection establishment), but if you want to make sure everything is bulletproof, you can setup a secondary key on the group owner device and exchange the key with the clients (the first thing after group is formed). And use the secondary key to encrypt data.

Sending: finalMessage = EncryptUsingGroupKey(message)
Receiving: finalMessage = DecryptUsingGroupKey(message)

The 'finalMessage' will also be encrypted/decrypted by WiFi P2P using the WPA2 passphrase.

For encryption/decryption with built-in integrity I would suggest using [Facebook Conceal](https://github.com/facebook/conceal). It makes crypto on Android extremely easy and fast. It's main purpose is for streaming bigger files (getCipherOutputStream and getCipherInputStream) but you can use the encrypt/decrypt functions for quick crypto on smaller stuff. You will however need to modify the base KeyChain to use a specific key, instead of generating a random one every time.

About the SSLSockets, you don't really need them; basic Java sockets should do the trick.